# Bootstrap 5 overflow-auto class cuts off the top of scrollable content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When I put text in a container like this, the top of the text is cut off ([pen](https://codepen.io/mottledpaper/pen/QWVGGJz)):

```html
<div class="align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center mb-3 overflow-auto" style="background-color: red; height: 5rem">
  <figure class="mb-0" style="background-color: orange">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center text-center" style="background-color: yellow">
      Hickory dickory dock.<br>
      The mouse ran up the clock.<br>
      The clock struck one,<br>
      The mouse ran down,<br>
      Hickory dickory dock.
    </div>
  </figure>
</div>
```

When I convert the Bootstrap classes to inline styles like this, the top of the text is not cut off ([pen](https://codepen.io/mottledpaper/pen/GRXNNzQ)):

```html
 <div style="align-items: center; background-color: red; display: flex; height: 5rem; justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 1rem; overflow: auto">
   <figure style="background-color: orange; margin-bottom: 0">
     <div style="background-color: yellow; display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center">
       Hickory dickory dock.<br>
       The mouse ran up the clock.<br>
       The clock struck one,<br>
       The mouse ran down,<br>
       Hickory dickory dock.
     </div>
   </figure>
 </div>
```

My questions are:

- Why?
- How can I keep the Bootstrap classes without cutting off the top of the content?

Note:

- The height cannot be changed. It can be customized by the user, and that means it's possible the content is larger than the container. When that's the case in both dimensions, the content should start scrolled to the top and left. That isn't happening.

Comment: `class="background-color: yellow; display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center"` I think here you should use `style` instead of `class`. Anyway, that may not fix your issue.

Comment: Fixed. That answered the color question. The scroll issue still remains. Thanks.